# How do I point Cygwins compiler to a different version of GCC

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin

For example I have

D:/MinGW with gcc version 4.6.1

D:/cygwin/usr/bin/gcc has version 4.5.x

I would like to make Cygwin use my 4.6.1 version of GCC

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okey you have installed cygwin and Mingw both so now to use gcc 4.6.1 version of cygwin

1> go in cygwin folder you will find cygwin.bat file so run that file and use gcc

2> if you are planning to use gcc 4.6.1 in your IDE then set path of cygwin folder in that IDE and also set your windows environment path to cygwin/bin

3> if you have already set environment path to cygwin  then open cmd write "bash" and start to use gcc 4.6.1

more you can find [at here](http://shareprogrammingtips.com/c-language-programming-tips/how-can-i-use-gcc-in-windowscmd-just-like-using-gcc-in-linux-terminal/)

Answer (score 0):

You can usually do this with a symlink or changing `PATH`

Cygwin (and most platforms) will run the first `gcc` it finds in the `PATH` environment variable. So:

If `PATH` is: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin` then you can symlink your 4.6 version of gcc into `/usr/local/bin` or you can add `/cygdrive/d/MinGW/` to the start of `PATH`.

However, note that cygwin and mingw are too separate platforms!